# Scale overlay image FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 inputs-- a background image, a text file containing list of image file location (to overlay on background image), and an audio file (to be played in background).

I need to scale the overlay images from "images.txt".
I am using below command.
I dont know what am I doing wrong.

```
command: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /sdcard/emoj/angry_bg.png -r 21.0 -f concat -i /sdcard/emoj/images.txt -i /sdcard/emoj/final.wav -filter_complex [1]scale=320:240 [ovrl],[0][ovrl] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 -shortest -s 1080x1920 -b:v 320k -codec:v h264 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 32k /sdcard/emoj/myPetVideo.mp4
```

Please give suggestions.

Logcat Output:

```
07-06 04:13:38.525: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): Command is set
07-06 04:13:38.525: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): set remoteNotificationIconId: 0
07-06 04:13:38.535: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client Cannot unbind - service not bound
07-06 04:13:38.535: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client stopService()
07-06 04:13:38.545: W/ContextImpl(28481): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge } android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:520 com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.stopService:495 com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.runTranscoing:279 
07-06 04:13:38.555: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!services.size(): 1
07-06 04:13:38.555: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): putting Base categoty
07-06 04:13:38.615: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): started: com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge
07-06 04:13:38.615: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client startService()
07-06 04:13:38.615: D/ffmpeg4android(28481):  bindService() called
07-06 04:13:38.615: W/ContextImpl(28481): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:538 com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.bindService:506 com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.runTranscoing:282 
07-06 04:13:38.625: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client bindService()
07-06 04:13:38.725: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): =======service onCreate(): Stopping forground (to overcome 2.3.x bug)
07-06 04:13:38.725: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): =======service onBind()=======
07-06 04:13:38.735: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): ===onStartCommand called
07-06 04:13:38.735: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client onServiceConnected()
07-06 04:13:38.735: E/ffmpeg4android(28481): invokeService called
07-06 04:13:38.735: E/rc......(28481): 1 
07-06 04:13:38.735: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): setting remote notification info
07-06 04:13:38.735: D/ffmpeg4android(28620): command items num: 33
07-06 04:13:38.735: D/ffmpeg4android(28620): command: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /sdcard/emoj/angry_bg.png -r 21.0 -f concat -i /sdcard/emoj/images.txt -i /sdcard/emoj/final.wav -filter_complex [1]scale=320:240 [ovrl],[0][ovrl] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 -shortest -s 1080x1920 -b:v 320k -codec:v h264 -c:v mpeg4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 32k /sdcard/emoj/myPetVideo.mp4
07-06 04:13:38.745: D/ffmpeg4android(28620): workingFolder from remote: /sdcard/emoj
07-06 04:13:38.745: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): deleteing: /sdcard/emoj/vk.log isdeleted: true
07-06 04:13:38.745: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): deleteing: /sdcard/emoj/ffmpeg4android.log isdeleted: false
07-06 04:13:38.745: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): deleteing: /sdcard/emoj/videokit.log isdeleted: true
07-06 04:13:38.745: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client invokeService()
07-06 04:13:38.755: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): ===onStartCommand cat: Base
07-06 04:13:38.755: D/ffmpeg4android(28620): onStartCommand, START_STICKY, base Command
07-06 04:13:38.755: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Acquire wake lock
07-06 04:13:38.765: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): TranscodeBackground doInBackground started
07-06 04:13:38.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): =======remote service runTranscoding ======
07-06 04:13:38.775: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): Start RemoteService with notification id: 5326
07-06 04:13:38.785: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): Run called.
07-06 04:13:38.785: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): ===============Running command from thread path: /sdcard/emoj
07-06 04:13:38.785: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): videokitLibPath: /data/data/org.vinuxproject.sonic/lib/libvideokit.so
07-06 04:13:38.785: I/Videokit(28620): dlopen libvideokit from path: /data/data/org.vinuxproject.sonic/lib/libvideokit.so
07-06 04:13:38.785: I/ffmpeg4android(28620): =======ProgressBackgroundRemote doInBackground=========
07-06 04:13:38.785: W/linker(28620): libvideokit.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): libvideokit.so loaded
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): args is not NULL
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): more then one arg
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): function symbol found
07-06 04:13:38.795: D/Videokit(28620): Calling videokit run via loader
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): vk ffmpeg sdcardPath: /sdcard/emoj 
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): licenseCheck in path: /sdcard/emoj 
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): isLicExistsComplex...
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): trying to open /sdcard/emoj/ffmpeglicense.lic 
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): license file found...
07-06 04:13:38.795: I/Videokit(28620): Permanent license validated.
07-06 04:13:38.795: D/Videokit(28620): license check rc: 1
07-06 04:13:38.795: D/Videokit(28620): run() called version 2.0
07-06 04:13:39.165: A/libc(28620): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 28620 (ct.sonic:remote)
07-06 04:13:39.655: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): onServiceDisconnected
07-06 04:13:40.805: I/ffmpeg4android(28656): =======service onCreate(): Stopping forground (to overcome 2.3.x bug)
07-06 04:13:40.805: I/ffmpeg4android(28656): =======service onBind()=======
07-06 04:13:40.815: I/ffmpeg4android(28656): ===onStartCommand called
07-06 04:13:40.815: D/ffmpeg4android(28656): Not running since the OS auto started the service after crash
07-06 04:13:40.815: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client onServiceConnected()
07-06 04:13:40.815: E/ffmpeg4android(28481): invokeService called
07-06 04:13:40.815: E/rc......(28481): 1 
07-06 04:13:40.815: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): setting remote notification info
07-06 04:13:40.815: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Not invoking
07-06 04:13:40.825: I/ffmpeg4android(28656): Cancel notification: 5326
07-06 04:13:41.135: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): Got real duration: 00:00:00.04
07-06 04:13:41.145: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): /sdcard/emoj/ffmpeg4android.log: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-06 04:13:41.145: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from FFmpeg4Android log
07-06 04:13:41.145: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:41.155: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:41.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:41.455: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:41.455: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentVkLogSize: 5316
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:41.465: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:41.465: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:41.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:41.765: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:41.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:41.765: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:41.765: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:41.765: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:41.765: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:41.775: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:41.775: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:42.075: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:42.075: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:42.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:42.375: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:42.375: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:42.375: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:42.385: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:42.385: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:42.385: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:42.385: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:42.385: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:42.385: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:42.685: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:42.685: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:42.685: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:42.685: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:42.685: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:42.695: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:42.695: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:42.695: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:42.695: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:42.995: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:42.995: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:42.995: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:43.295: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:43.295: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:43.305: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:43.305: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:43.605: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:43.605: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:43.615: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:43.615: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:43.915: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:43.915: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:43.915: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:43.915: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:43.915: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:43.915: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:43.915: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:43.925: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:43.925: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:44.225: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:44.225: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:44.225: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:44.525: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:44.525: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:44.525: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:44.535: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:44.535: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:44.535: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:44.535: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:44.535: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:44.535: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:44.835: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:44.835: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:44.835: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:44.835: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:44.835: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:44.835: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:44.835: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:44.845: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:44.845: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:45.155: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:45.155: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:45.155: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:45.455: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:45.455: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:45.455: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:45.755: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:45.755: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:45.765: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:45.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:46.065: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:46.065: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:46.065: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:46.075: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:46.075: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:46.075: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:46.075: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:46.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:46.075: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:46.375: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:46.375: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:46.375: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:46.375: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:46.375: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:46.375: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:46.385: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:46.385: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not setting
07-06 04:13:46.385: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): progress is 0, not publishing
07-06 04:13:46.685: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ==== getting currentVkLogSize from VK
07-06 04:13:46.685: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): Looks like Vk log is not increasing in size
07-06 04:13:46.685: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): No ffmpeg4android_log file, using vk log
07-06 04:13:46.685: I/line(28481): a suitable output format for '[ovrl],[0][ovrl]'
07-06 04:13:46.685: I/line(28481): [ovrl],[0][ovrl]: Invalid argument
07-06 04:13:46.685: I/line(28481): exit_program: 1 
07-06 04:13:46.685: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): currentTimeStr: 00:00:00.00
07-06 04:13:46.685: E/ffmpeg4android(28481): VK log is not changing in size, and no exit token found
07-06 04:13:46.695: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): onProgressUpdate: 100
07-06 04:13:46.695: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Releasing wake lock
07-06 04:13:46.695: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): TranscodeBackground onPostExecute
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): progressDialog failed to dismiss: null
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481): android.os.DeadObjectException
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.IFfmpgefRemoteServiceBridge$Stub$Proxy.setTranscodingProgress(IFfmpgefRemoteServiceBridge.java:181)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.TranscodeBackground.onPostExecute(TranscodeBackground.java:163)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.TranscodeBackground.onPostExecute(TranscodeBackground.java:1)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
07-06 04:13:46.705: W/ffmpeg4android(28481):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
07-06 04:13:46.715: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): /sdcard/emoj/null length in bytes: 0
07-06 04:13:46.715: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): showNotifications
07-06 04:13:46.715: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): ============ Transcoding Failed, caling fexist
07-06 04:13:46.715: E/ffmpeg4android(28481): fexit remote excetion
07-06 04:13:46.765: I/ffmpeg4android(28481): FFMPEG finished.
07-06 04:13:46.985: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): releaseService()
07-06 04:13:46.985: D/ffmpeg4android(28481): Client stopService()
07-06 04:13:46.985: I/ffmpeg4android(28656): =======service onDestroy()======
07-06 04:13:46.985: W/ContextImpl(28481): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge } android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:520 com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.stopService:495 org.vinuxproject.sonic.WaveformActivity.handleServiceFinished:456
```

Comment: Here are few mistakes I'm seeing. You are using two video encoders together which is confusing. To make yourself clear `-codec:v` and `-c:v`are the same for video encoding. For `filter_complex` you should use quotations as you are chaining the filters. As a best practice use `[0:v]` or `[1:a]` instead of only specifying the index like `[0]`.

Comment: @Chamath What is "v" and "a" in [0:v] or [1:a]?

Comment: well, `[0:v]` is referring to the video channel of the first input and `[1:a]` is referring to the audio channel of the second input. If you have an audio source with multiple audio channels you can further be specific for each channel like `[0:a:1]` which is second audio channel of the first input.